# angular scope update doesn't update html list

Tags: angularjs

I have this code to create a list:

```
    <tr class="customer-row" ng-repeat="customer in Customers" id="{{customer.CustomerId}}" ng-mouseover="getUsers(customer.CustomerId)">
            <td class="col-xs-1">{{customer.CustomerId}}</td>
            <td class="col-xs-6">{{customer.CustomerName}}</td>
            <td class="col-xs-1">{{customer.CountryCode}}</td>
            <td class="col-xs-1">{{customer.CustomerERPId}}</td>
            <td class="col-xs-1"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></td>
        </tr>
```

i do this by using this code:

```
 $http.post("/User/GetBy?customerId=" + customerId)
     .then(function (response) {
         $scope.Users = response.data;
     });
```

this is triggerd when a dropdown is changed.

I also have a textbox that i want the user to search through customer so i have a ng-keyup event which end up here.

```
 $http.post("/Customer/SearchCustomers?supplierId=" + $('#supplier').val() + "&searchText=" + $('#search-btn').val())
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                $scope.Customers = response.data;
            });
    }
```

I get all the users and add them to the customers in the scope. 
This is the first time i'm doing anything in angular but i was told when i update the scope it should update the html. 
Shouldn't the list be updated then? Or do i have to trigger something for it to update my list?

Comment: You can try to use angular.copy(response.data, $scope.Users);

Comment: Why 'POST' instead of 'GET'? Do you have that <table> in a directive or is everything under same controller/link? Are you getting correct 'response.data' in console?

Comment: I think you may also want to read up on this [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) which should help you out with your post to `SearchCustomers`. Secondly you should look at `ngModel` because that is how you get the `$('#supplier').val()` without using jQuery

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! They are in different controllers since the searchfield is in another view then the list. Is that why it doesn't update?

Comment: If your table is in another scope (made by directive/controller) then that '$http' logic will not update your view. Also make sure that you're getting an 'OK' (200) response. You don't have second function in then() that is responsible for handling an 'ERROR' response (ex. put there a console.error('Some message').